# How to store Generated number from 1 to 500 in two Array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, initializer-list

I have generate random number from 1 to 500 and want to store in 2 arrays says array1(store 1 to 250 elements) and array2(store 251 to 500 elements). Size of Both array is 250. I successfully store in array1 but not in array2.

I tried but the loop goes on Infinite loop

```
#define MAX 250
int a1[MAX], a2[MAX];
srand((int)time(0));

for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    int c = (rand() % 500) + 1;
    if (i >= 0 && i < 250) {
        cout << "Array 1 ";
        for (j = 0; j < 250; j++) {
            a1[j] = c;
            cout << a1[j] << " ";
        }
    }
    if (i >= 250 && i < 500) {
        cout << endl
             << "Array 2 ";
        for (int k = 0; k < 250; k++) {
            a2[k] = c;
            cout << a2[k] << " ";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `MAX`? Present your [mcve].

Comment: The code works for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6160d9a16d1ccf8b

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit MAX is size of array. I Have define the size of Max is 250.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, and I cannot see how this code can fill `a1` correctly.

Comment: What is the reason for the inner loop that fills all 250 elements with the same random number and also prints the number 250 times as it fills?

Comment: You should check out : [Pseudo-random number generation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) and [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Answer (score 2):

It's not looping infinitely; it's just looping *too much*.

That's because you put a loop in a loop (dawg).

You don't want those inner `for` loops at all.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    const size_t MAX = 250;
    int a1[MAX], a2[MAX];

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( auto a : { a1, a2 } )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < MAX; i++ ) a[i] = std::rand() % ( 2 * MAX ) + 1;
    }        
}
```

As for your code then the inner loops

```
for (j = 0; j < 250; j++) {
```

and

```
for (int k = 0; k < 250; k++) {
```

are executed 500 times because they are enclosed in the outer loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 500; i++)
```

Comment: Good handing out of fish!